# How to find and replace lines in the build.gradle before executing it, using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a build.gradle file which usually been executed in a windows environment; but when the same file is checked out in a Linux environment, the batch file mentioned in some of the lines gets conflicted, so what we were trying is to replace the exact lines where the build gets failed, to the lines that makes it work, using a shell script after the checkout gets completed.

**build.gradle file**

```
......
......
task exportBatch(type:Exec) {
    doFirst {
        println "Exporting batch..."
        commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'export.bat']
    }
}
task importBatch(type:Exec) {
    doFirst {
        println "Importing batch..."
        commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'import.bat']
    }
}
.....
.....
```

I would like to achieve the following before executing the build; after the source codes gets checked out to local workspace.

In **task exportBatch**, the line to be used is

> **commandLine 'sh', './export.sh'**

instead of

> **commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'export.bat']**

and
in **task importBatch**, the line to be used

> **commandLine 'sh', './import.sh'**

instead of

> **commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'import.bat']**

We tired changing the line based on the line number, but when there is a change of line numbers our method fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` you can try

```
$ sed "/exportBatch/,/}/ {s|commandLine =.*|commandLine 'sh', './export.sh'|}; /importBatch/,/}/ {s|commandLine =.*|commandLine 'sh', './import.sh'|}" input_file
......
......
task exportBatch(type:Exec) {
    doFirst {
        println Exporting batch...
        commandLine 'sh', './export.sh'
    }
}
task importBatch(type:Exec) {
    doFirst {
        println Importing batch...
        commandLine 'sh', './import.sh'
    }
}
.....
.....
```

`/exportBatch/,/}/` - Match between `exportBatch` and `}`

`s|commandLine =.*|commandLine 'sh', './export.sh'|` - Within the match above, substitute the line with content `commandLine =.*` with `commandLine 'sh', './export.sh'` **NOTE** Double quotation was used.

`|` - The pipe was used as a delimiter but any symbol that does not appear in the data can be used as the delimiter. As your data had `/`, the default `sed` delimiter could not be used as it would conflict and cause an error.

The same conditions are repeated in the second part of the code to handle the second substitution.

Comment: Thanks @HatLess; it solved my problem. it would be helpful if you can explain your answer.

Comment: Sure @Wolf Give me a moment to type it.